# Double condition Fibonacci sequence in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a Fibonacci sequence which incrementation depends on one column and then restarts depends on another column.

Given columns `A` and `B`, I'd like to calculate `FIB`:

```
 A | B |FIB
---|---|---
 1 | T | 0    // A=1, B=T -> FIB=0
 2 | T | 1    // A!=1, B=T -> FIB=1
 0 | F |      // B=F -> Do Nothing
 2 | T | 1    // A!=1, B=T -> FIB=FIB(-1)+FIB(-2)=1
 2 | T | 2    // A!=1, B=T -> FIB=FIB(-1)+FIB(-2)=2
 0 | T | 3    // A!=1, B=T -> FIB=FIB(-1)+FIB(-2)=3
 2 | F |      // B=F -> Do Nothing
 1 | F |      // B=F -> Do Nothing
 2 | T | 5    // A!=1, B=T -> FIB=FIB(-1)+FIB(-2)=5
 0 | F |      // B=F -> Do Nothing
 1 | T | 0    // A=1, B=T -> Restart -> FIB=0
 2 | T | 1    // A!=1, B=T -> FIB=1
 0 | F |      // B=F -> Do Nothing
 0 | T | 1    // A!=1, B=T -> FIB=FIB(-1)+FIB(-2)=1
 2 | T | 2    // A!=1, B=T -> FIB=FIB(-1)+FIB(-2)=2
```

When `A=1` I want FIB to restart the Fibonacci sequence.

When `B=T` I want FIB to increment.

Do you see any way, without VB, to do this?

My attempt --

```
FIB =IF(B, IF(A=1,0,FIB[-1] + FIB[-2]))
```

This doesn't work because the increment is not taking into consideration that the previous cells may be empty or may be a restart.

Comment: Where’s your attempt? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Thanks @EdCottrell. Added my attempt.

Comment: It is completely unclear what you want to achieve. *When A=1 I want FIB to restart the Fibonacci sequence.* And when ``A`` is ``2`` or ``0``?

Comment: Thanks @datell. I thought the example made it clear. When `A` is anything else than `1`, if `B=T` then I want  the sequence to increment. So, basically, if `B=T` then increment, if `À<>1`, or restart, if `A=1`. Do nothing if `B=F`.

Comment: @Oliveira *So, basically, if B=T then increment* by what? By ``1`` or by the number in ``A``? Where does the  ``5`` come from? The restart only happens if ``B=T``? You example clarifies nothing to be honest.

Comment: @datell it's a Fibonacci sequence. So it increments by the sum of the previous two values. `5` comes from `2+3`.

Comment: @Oliveira Then I guess that the sequence doesn't restart even though the row above contains ``1`` because ``B=F`` is this case?

Comment: @datell exactly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173722/discussion-between-datell-and-oliveira).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution, with the aid of some helper columns

In cell `G2`

```
=IF($B2="T",IF($A2=1,0,IF($B1="T",-1,$G1)),$G1-1)
```

In cell `H2`

```
=INDEX($G:$G,ROW()+$G2)+$G2
```

In cell `I2`

```
=INDEX($C:$C,ROW()+$G2)
```

In cell `J2`

```
=INDEX($C:$C,ROW()+$H2)
```

And in FIB cell, `C2`

```
=IF(B5="T",IF(A5=1,0,IF($I5=0,1,$I5+$J5)),"")
```

And copy down as far as required

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.